# MySQL query: Select column, then delete the row

Tags: mysql

I am attempting to delete rows for which I know the ID, but I want to return the value of one of the columns from the query (a select and delete in one query)

```
SELECT 'scheme' FROM colors WHERE ID = 4
DELETE FROM colors WHERE ID = 4
```

How can I combine these two queries?

Comment: stored proc as I see it (don't tell Tadman) :p

Comment: You could just have 2 queries and be done with it